# Snake collides with itself if user presses arrow keys too fast

Tags: javascript

Iv'e finished my snake game but there's one more bug I can't fix. If the snake is going left for example the user can hit the up key then the right key quick enough so the snake never has a chance to move up 1 unit and resulting in the snake head turning in on itself. Any ideas how I could fix this? My brains telling me I need to have the snake move up 1 unit first before turning right, I just don't know what that looks like

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');
const gameOver = document.querySelector('.game-over');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//load audio files
let eat = new Audio();
let dead = new Audio();
eat.src = 'audio/eat.mp3';
dead.src = 'audio/dead.mp3';

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create points variable 
let points = 0;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x-unit/2, snake[i].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 }
 //draw food
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);

 //grab heads position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //move snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new snake unit
 let newHead = {x : headX, y :headY}

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall or itself
 if(headX < 0 || headX > cvsW || headY < 0 || headY > cvsH || collision(headX, headY)) {
  dead.play();
  clearInterval(runGame);
  canvas.style.animationName = 'animate';
  setTimeout(function() {gameOver.style.opacity = '1';}, 150);
 }

 //check to see if snakes eaten food
 if(headX === food.x && headY === food.y) {
  eat.play();
  //increase score
  points++;
  score.innerText = points;
  //get new food unit
  getFood();
  //create 3 new units
  for(let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
   //add those units -without this code snake will not grow 
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 } else {
  //remove tail -without this code snake will keep growing
  snake.pop();
 }
 //add new head position -without this code snake will not move
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

let runGame = setInterval(draw, 65);

function collision(x, y) {
 for(let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function getFood() {
 food = {
  x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
  y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
 }
 //loop through snake to see if food generates inside snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //if so call the function again
  if(food.x == snake[i].x && food.y == snake[i].y) return getFood();
 } 
 //else return new random point
 return food;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Square" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  .game-over {
   z-index: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 784px;
   height: 528px;
   margin: auto;
   color: red;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 5rem;
   font-weight: bolder;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   opacity: 0;
   text-shadow: -7px 7px #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   animation-duration: 0.1s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes animate {
   0% {left: 0; right: 0;}
   25% {left: 50px; right: 0;}
   50% {left: 0; right: 50px;}
   75% {left: 50px; right: 0;}
   100% {left: 0; right: 0;}
  }

  .score {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 4rem;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="score">0</div>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="784" height="528"></canvas>
 <div class="game-over">Game Over</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a boolean such as `CanTurn` and check to see if the user can turn. Set it to false when they turn (press the arrow), then set it to true on the next position change (such as the next second).

Comment: + for nice snippet :)

Comment: Thank you:) I wish you could hear the audio I had with it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to hold the next direction, then update the actual direction from `draw`, so it will be in synch with what is actually happening:

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');
const gameOver = document.querySelector('.game-over');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//load audio files
let eat = new Audio();
let dead = new Audio();
eat.src = 'audio/eat.mp3';
dead.src = 'audio/dead.mp3';

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create points variable 
let points = 0;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;
let nextDirection

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') nextDirection = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') nextDirection = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') nextDirection = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') nextDirection = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x-unit/2, snake[i].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 }
 //draw food
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);

 //grab heads position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //move snake in chosen direction
 if(nextDirection == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(nextDirection == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(nextDirection == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(nextDirection == 'down') headY += unit;
 // update the direction the snake is travelling:
 direction = nextDirection;

 //create new snake unit
 let newHead = {x : headX, y :headY}

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall or itself
 if(headX < 0 || headX > cvsW || headY < 0 || headY > cvsH || collision(headX, headY)) {
  dead.play();
  clearInterval(runGame);
  canvas.style.animationName = 'animate';
  setTimeout(function() {gameOver.style.opacity = '1';}, 150);
 }

 //check to see if snakes eaten food
 if(headX === food.x && headY === food.y) {
  eat.play();
  //increase score
  points++;
  score.innerText = points;
  //get new food unit
  getFood();
  //create 3 new units
  for(let i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
   //add those units -without this code snake will not grow 
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 } else {
  //remove tail -without this code snake will keep growing
  snake.pop();
 }
 //add new head position -without this code snake will not move
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

let runGame = setInterval(draw, 65);

function collision(x, y) {
 for(let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function getFood() {
 food = {
  x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
  y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
 }
 //loop through snake to see if food generates inside snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  //if so call the function again
  if(food.x == snake[i].x && food.y == snake[i].y) return getFood();
 } 
 //else return new random point
 return food;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Square" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  .game-over {
   z-index: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 784px;
   height: 528px;
   margin: auto;
   color: red;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 5rem;
   font-weight: bolder;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   opacity: 0;
   text-shadow: -7px 7px #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   animation-duration: 0.1s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes animate {
   0% {left: 0; right: 0;}
   25% {left: 50px; right: 0;}
   50% {left: 0; right: 50px;}
   75% {left: 50px; right: 0;}
   100% {left: 0; right: 0;}
  }

  .score {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Nova Square';
   font-size: 4rem;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="score">0</div>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="784" height="528"></canvas>
 <div class="game-over">Game Over</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```